# How to generate SHA for integrity html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, sha, integrity

I'm using this command to generate SHA hash in command line on my Mac:

```
openssl dgst -sha384 -binary FILENAME.js | openssl base64 -A
```

The result looks like this:

```
93Zn4wbvkSu+.......PksSwU4A+2a.....t0OOmyCompName:public
```

I then paste this sha with prefix in `integrity` html attribute: Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-93Zn4wbvkSu+.......PksSwU4A+2a.....t0OOmyCompName:public">
```

And Chrome gives me an error:

```
Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('sha384-93Zn4wbvkSu+.......PksSwU4A+2a.....t0OOmyCompName:public'). The digest must be a valid, base64-encoded value.
```

I tried with `myCompName:public` and without. Help me please - how to correctly generate this integrity hash?

I don't use https://www.srihash.org/ because no cors enabled. Nginx serves my static files.

Comment: Is sha384- should be part of the hashed value?

Comment: Yes it's documented. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Answer (score 2):

I found an error. Do not include in your integrity token this text in the end:

```
myCompName:public
```

If you delete `-A` key from you command in the end it will give you the same result but without name of your local machine and :public word ending.

so the right hash will look like this:

```
sha384-93Zn4wbvkSu+.......PksSwU4A+2a.....t0OO
```

Comment: For completeness: `openssl dgst -sha384 -binary FILENAME.js | openssl base64` is the proper command.